# What is the difference between Container and DisplayObjectContainer?

Tags: javascript, html, pixi.js

I am using a JavaScript library called PIXI and am looking for a way to "zoom" in my game. A search on the internet suggested that I put everything inside a `DisplayObjectContainer`and then resize it to simulate a zoom-effect.

The thing is that I already have `Container` (aka `stage`), and I think that is resizable too. So I don't understand the reason behind using a `DisplayObjectContainer`when you have a `Container`already. And frankly, I don't even see the difference between them.

[This page](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/classes/DisplayObjectContainer.html) says the following about `DisplayObjectContainer`:

> A DisplayObjectContainer represents a collection of display objects. It is the base class of all display objects that act as a container for other objects.

[This other page](https://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.Container.html) says the following about `Container`:

> A Container represents a collection of display objects. It is the base class of all display objects that act as a container for other objects.

The only possible scenario I can imagine is that one of these container-objects is outdated and belongs to an older version of PIXI, which isn't too unrealistic since PIXI is rather new and could change a lot. But this is just a guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The guess is correct. `DisplayObjectContainer` is outdated and replaced with `Container`.

Comment: It would be better to link or quote some source with this claim.